# Is it redundant to set bindingMode with produces and consumes?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, apache-camel

I wonder is it redundant to use 
`consumes` and `procudes` with `bindingMode` ?

```
        rest()
                .description("rest service provider")
                .consumes("application/xml").produces("application/xml")
                .post("/start").type(P.class)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml)
                .description("Service to start a test process")
                .route().routeId("REST").log("Message send: \n ${body}")
```

Should i use only one of these lines ? What's the difference?

```
                .consumes("application/xml").produces("application/xml")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use ***.bindingMode*** on the **restConfiguration** to biding xml/json to/from POJO.
And you use ***.consume*** or ***.produces*** in the rest VERB action to specify the type you want to receive or produce.

```
restConfiguration()
   .component("restlet|jetty|servlet")
   .host("localhost")
   .port(portNum)
   .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

 rest("/url/")
    .get("/bye").consumes("application/json")
    .to("direct:bye")
```